# hide object information in matlab

Tags: matlab, class, output

I implemented a class in Matlab which derives from matlab.mixin.Copyable. I want to suppress the output of the command window so that the user does not has information about the class. I want to do this for security reasons. For example:

```
a = myStack;
a

ans=

myStack with no properties.
```

But the user can click myStack and it gives information about the class. I know that I can overload display for this, but the behavior that I want is like follows:

```
b = handle(1);
b

ans=

handle
```

How I can do this?
Thanks.

Comment: Be aware that `struct(a)` reveals all properties. What exactly do you want to protect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to derive from [matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/matlab_oop/type-sect1-title-here.html) interface and override the [getPropertyGroups](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.customdisplay.getpropertygroups.html) method.

For the specific purpose of removing the link to help in the header, also override [getHeader](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/matlab.mixin.customdisplay.getheader.html) method.

NB: I don't see how you can truly handle *security* in this way. Users will still have other means to get details about your class. For instance `meta = ?MyClass`, or just `edit MyClass` if not encrypted with [pcode](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html), or simply in the editor just typing `myInstance.` and let intellisense list all [non hidden/private](http://www.mathworks.fr/fr/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-attributes.html) methods and properties.

Example for the display you want to have:

```
classdef foo < matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay

    properties        
        Login = 'root';
        Password = '1234'        
    end

    methods (Access = protected)        
        function [str] = getHeader(obj)
            str = mfilename;
        end
        function [pg] = getPropertyGroups(obj)
            pg = [];
        end
        function [str] = getFooter(obj)
           str = sprintf('\n');
        end        
   end

end
```

May be better solution to avoid displaying some properties (including from help-link):

```
classdef foo < matlab.mixin.CustomDisplay

    properties (SetAccess = private, GetAccess = private) % here remove any public access, use '(Hidden)' if only want to remove from display and help        
        Login = 'root';
        Password = '1234'        
    end       

end
```

NB: Careful, as @Daniel wrote, whatever you will do, `struct(a)` reveals all property names and values.

Answer (score 1):

As well as the method from @CitizenInsane, you may get what you want by simply adding the `Hidden = true` attribute to some or all of your properties.

Reiterating what others have said, though, if you're doing this in order to seriously prevent people from understanding the internals of your class, `struct(a)` will always show them the properties. You can overload your class with a `struct` method that errors out, but then `builtin('struct', a)` would still do the original thing. Also `?Classname` will provide meta-information about the class that includes its properties.

Comment: is there a way to fully prevent this?

Comment: No. You could obfuscate the property names though, for example call them Hidden1, Hidden2 etc.